# How do I add my own completions to sublime text 3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I've been looking everywhere for an answer and I can't seem to make sense of anything I find.  There's either to references to files that don't exist in my installation, or the file does exist but is just raw hexadecimal data rather than code.  For example, I keep seeing that I should look in my packages/(insert programming language here) folder to access autocompletion files for that particular language.  Unfortunately, when I click browse packages, the folder only contains a bz2 folder and a User folder.

I'm trying to modify sublime text's PHP autocompletion and make it so that whenever I type

```
<?
```

I can hit enter and it would autocomplete to

```
<?php ?>
```

with the cursor set between the tags.  I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11085403/writing-custom-completions-in-sublime-text-2) as well but as I said earlier I've had problems getting any of these solutions to work for me.

How do I add this simple autocompletion to my sublime text 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by adding snippets. Just go to **Tools** > **New Snippet...**. There's a lot of docs about how to write a snippet.

Also, in your case, you can install the **Additional PHP Snippets** and trigger that completition by typing `php` and hitting tab